# Using GAN to Model Posteriors with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I have a 5-dimensional dataset and I'm interested in using a neural network to model the posterior distributions from which the data was drawn. I decided to implement a GAN to do this, and have been familiarizing myself with PyTorch.

I'm wondering how one should go about restricting what values the generator can produce for the parameters. For one of the parameters, the values must be nonnegative real values. For another case, the values must be nonnegative integer values. For the other three cases, the parameters can take on any real value.

My first idea was to control this through the transfer function applied to the nodes in the output layer of my neural network. But all of the PyTorch examples I've seen so far apply the same transfer function to *all* of the output nodes, which is not what I want to do. Is there a way to apply a different transfer function to each output node? Or is there maybe a better way to approach this problem?